# copying and pasting range depending on a condition

Tags: vba, excel

For past few days I am struggling to write macro that would be able to do the following things:
1.Copy particular cells from one sheet (whether to copy them or not depends on a condition)
2.Pasted them into specified sheet (its name is secified by a formula) into specified cells (they are specified by a formula too).

Unfortunately I cannot paste images, so I will try to explain what I am trying to do by pasting a sketch of the code with questions. If this vague please let me know.

```
Sub The_One()
'
For Each c In Worksheets("fsr").Range("O:O")
    If c.Value = "p" Then
    'Now I do not know how to make Excel copy the cells from current row from columns E,F,G,H
    'Now I would like to add cells into the worksheet which name is sepcified by the formula from column P.
    'Inserted cells should be added into a row given by the formula in column Q.
    'I imagine it like that:
        Sheets("group1").Select 'This "group1" cannot be simply tiped into the code, it should be taken from Column P in worksheet("fsr")
        Range("A3:I3").Select 'As above, the range should be specified more like that:
                              'Range("A[row number given by a formula in column Q in Worksheet("fsr")]:I[the same number as before]
        Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
            'Now I would like to copy four cells from Worksheet("fsr") they are in the same row as the current cell from above For Each
            'I imagine it somehow like that:
            Range("E'Here I dont know how to define the row number':H'The same problem'").Activate
            ActiveCell.CurrentRegion.Select 'Is CurrentRegion suitable?
            Selection.Copy
            Worksheets("group1").Select 'But this worksheet should be the one that is given by a formula in column P in Worksheet("fsr")
            Range("E'Here I dont know how to define the row number':F'The same problem'").Activate
            ActiveSheet.Paste 'But I dont want to paste it anywhere. It sholud be pasted into the worksheet given by the formula from column P,
                              'into the row given by the formula from column Q, into the columns C,D,E,F. So:
                              'So when the For Each starts to go trough Range("O:O") in Worksheet("fsr") it notices that there is "p" so it should:
                              'copy cells E2:H2 (because this "p" is in the second row) and paste it in the Worksheet("group1") (because this is what
                              'we find in cell P2 into the cells C3:F3 (row 3 because "3" is what we find in Q2)
    End If
Next c
End Sub
```

I am new to Stackoverflow so I would appreciate all the comments concernig my conduct here.
I hope that You will find a second to help me, I really need your help.
with best regards
Artur Rutkowski

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your response. By pastin a link you mean, pasting link to the images on a external server, do you?
Anyways, is my question too vague to be answered?
With best regards,
asking kindly for help,
Artur Rutkowski

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
For Each c In Worksheets("fsr").Range("O:O") 
'This will slow your macro as Excel will search all 1048576 rows
'I suggest you define the range of data in another sheet
```

Starting Row | 1
Ending Row   | 30

```
Sub The_One()
startrow = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1,1)
endrow = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(2,1)

For x = startrow to endrow
    If Cells(x,"O").Value = "p" Then
        Range("E" & x, "H" & x).Copy
        Worksheets(Cells(x, "P").Value).Cells(Cells(x, "Q").Value, "C").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
    End If
    Next    
End Sub
```

Comment: Alternatively to find the last row you can use the following code: endrow = Range("O:O").End(xlDown).Row

Comment: Thanks a lot Siddharth Sawjiani! You made my day!